# Add URL parameters to XML Sitemap?

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap

I am creating an XML sitemap for my website and I'm stuck with this question: what do you do about URL's with parameters in them?

For instance I have a user profile page with the url:
https://www.websitename.com/profiles.php?User_ID=xx

The URL https://www.websitename.com/profiles/ redirect to the mainpage because no User_ID has been set.

How would I go about adding this to a sitemap? Do I have to add it at all?

I understand that adding static pages like Contact and About and such is required, but what about the above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes in this case you have to add all the links with all the available IDs you have in your website.

There is another solution, you can add all the users you have in one page (/profiles-list) and submit only this page, in this case Google will crawl them and index them 100%.

If you want to use the above solution, add in the  noindex,follow because we don't want Google to index this page and at the same time follow the links inside it.

If i where you, i will add all the links to the sitemap.